# Writing data into json file

Tags: java, arrays, json

I need to write some information into the JSON file.

I have written the following function:

```
public String toJSON() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    sb.append("\"" + MyConstants.VEHICLE_LABEL + "\":");
    sb.append("{");
    sb.append("\"" + MyConstants.CAPACITY1_LABEL + "\": " + String.valueOf(this.getCapacity(0)) +  ",");
    sb.append("\"" + MyConstants.CAPACITY2_LABEL + "\": " + String.valueOf(this.getCapacity(1)) +  ",");
    sb.append("\"" + MyConstants.CAPACITY3_LABEL + "\": " + String.valueOf(this.getCapacity(2)));   
    sb.append("}");

    return sb.toString();
}
```

However, I want to make this function more flexible. In particular, how should I change this code if the number of capacity units is not fixed (1, 2 or 3)?

I think that there should be a FOOR loop, however I am not sure how to implement it correctly.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a json parser like gson or jackson?

Comment: @azurefrog: This topic is new for me. I am just improving the code that I received from another person. So, I would appreciate if someone explain me how to answer the question based on this code without using any parser.

Comment: If I were asked to improve the code I would suggest using the proper tools/libraries rather than hacking something together. If they don't agree with me (or the other person may be offended or something) and think it's better to re-invent the wheel then I would do it their way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could do the append only if `this.getCapacity(i)` is not empty.

You could do something like this with a for loop

```
for(int i=0; i < max; i++) {
    if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(String.valueOf(this.getCapacity(i)))){
        sb.append("\"" + String.format(MyConstants.CAPACITY_LABEL, i) + "\": " + String.valueOf(this.getCapacity(i)) +  ",");
    }
}
```

where `MyConstants.CAPACITY_LABEL` is something like "capacity%d_label"

But, as azurefrog said, I would use a json parser to do this.

Comment: Yeah, the really hard part is going to be if the capacity labels are all random text.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following class that follows the popular builder pattern:

```
public class JsonVehicleBuilder {

    private StringBuilder builder;

    /**
     *  Starts off the builder with the main label
     */
    public JsonVehicleBuilder(String mainLabel) {
        builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append("\"").append(mainLabel).append("\":");
        builder.append("{");
    }

    public JsonVehicleBuilder appendSimpleValue(String label, String value) {
        builder.append("\"").append(label).append("\":").append(value).append(",");
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Appends the closing bracket and outputs the final JSON
     */
    public String build() {
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.lastIndexOf(",")); //remove last comma
        builder.append("}");
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

And then in your main method you would call:

```
   JsonVehicleBuilder jsonVehicleBuilder = new JsonVehicleBuilder(MyConstants.VEHICLE_LABEL);
    jsonVehicleBuilder.appendSimpleValue(MyConstants.CAPACITY1_LABEL,String.valueOf(this.getCapacity(0)))
            .appendSimpleValue(MyConstants.CAPACITY2_LABEL,String.valueOf(this.getCapacity(1)))
            .appendSimpleValue(MyConstants.CAPACITY3_LABEL,String.valueOf(this.getCapacity(2)));

    String json = jsonVehicleBuilder.build();
```

You can then keep chaining the appendSimpleValue method as long as you like.